# C# // How to close console in a middle of else if statement // beginner

Tags: c#, if-statement, close-application

```
        Write("Hello, what is you name? ");
        customer = ReadLine();
        WriteLine($"Nice to meet you, {customer}. What kind of pizza would you like?");

        pizza = ReadLine();
        if (pizza == "Sausage")
        {
            WriteLine("Nice, that will be 20.00");
        }
        else if (pizza != "Sausage")
        {
            WriteLine("Make up your mind");
        }
```

//////////////////////How do I close in this instance? For answer is not sausage

Comment: I have code after this, but I only want that to appear if I input Sausage. If I don't input Sausage, I just want the console to close. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you return from the Main method that will end the application. I have moved the code around a little bit to demonstrate this.

```
Console.Write("Hello, what is you name? ");
var customer = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine($"Nice to meet you, {customer}. What kind of pizza would you like?");

var pizza = Console.ReadLine();

if(pizza != "Sausage")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Make up your mind");
    return;
}
Console.WriteLine("Nice, that will be 20.00");
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. I am just picking up C# in my class. This my first semester and I just wanted to play around with what we learned.